# Setting Constructor Teller in Main() to call specific accounts in a method

Tags: java

In this code I am making a Bank Account of sorts. It has a basic BankAccount that has variables Name and id. It has a savings account that has interest and a checking account with a credit line. Both of those classes extends to the BankAccountInfo class.

In the Teller class I have a constructor Teller with a name and date processed that is set in the Main(). I have a method called setUpAccts() that includes the accounts I have created so far, the checking, savings and two basic bankaccounts.

In the Main() I want to be be able to have multiple tellers calling specific accounts.

For example, I want Teller John to only call acct1, which would be the checking account. Then I want another teller, Kate, to only call acct2, the savings account and it's content.

As it stands I only have a single Teller calling every single account in the setUpAccts() method.

Here is the Teller code.

EDIT: Sorry for having a horrible description, I hope the new one makes my problem more clear.

```
class Teller
{
    String name;
    String dateProcessed;
    int random;

    public Teller(String n, String dP)
    {
        name = n;
        dateProcessed = dP;

        System.out.println("Teller:" + " " + name + " " + "This transaction will process:" + " " + dateProcessed);
    }

public void setUpAccts()
    {
        CheckingAccount acct1 = new CheckingAccount("Dylan Kuchar", 11, "Checking");
        //acct1.setCheckingAccount("Dylan", "11", "Checking", acct1.getOverdraft());
        acct1.printCheckingAccount();
        acct1.setBalance(250);
        //acct1.printBalance();
        acct1.withdraw(120.5);
        //acct1.printBalance();

        SavingsAccount acct2 = new SavingsAccount("Emily Doe", 2, "Savings");
        acct2.printSavingsAccount();
        acct2.setBalance(225.5);
        acct2.InterestBalance();
        acct2.withdraw(500);

        BankAccountInfo acct3 = new BankAccountInfo();
        acct3.BankAccountInfo("Dylan", 11);
        acct3.printBankAccountInfo();
        acct3.setBalance(150);
        acct3.deposit(20);
        acct3.printBalance();

        BankAccountInfo acct4 = new BankAccountInfo();
        acct4.BankAccountInfo("Emily", 2);
        acct4.printBankAccountInfo();
        acct4.setBalance(650);
        acct4.withdraw(150);
        acct4.printBalance();
    }



    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Teller t = new Teller("John", "Today");
        t.setUpAccts();

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?????

Comment: You seem to be assuming we understand the context involving tellers, "John", and "accounts", which we don't.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good SO questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the simple way is simply making a teller a specific type on initialization. So your code would change to:

```
class Teller
{
String name;
String dateProcessed;
Boolean Savings; 
int random;

public Teller(String n, String dP, Boolean Savings)
{
    name = n;
    dateProcessed = dP;
    this.Savings = Savings;

    System.out.println("Teller:" + " " + name + " " + "This transaction will process:"     + " " + dateProcessed);
}
```

then you just change your setUpAccts class to only deal with one Person. and place a if else to see if the teller is dealing with savings or checking. prolly not the best, but its what came to mind.

Edit:

What you can do is create a Class called Account, CheckingAccount and Savings Account would inherit from this class. You can then do this:

```
class Teller
{
Account acct;
String name;
String dateProcessed;
int random;

public Teller(Account act, String dP)
{
    acct=act;
    name = acct.getname();
    dateProcessed = dP;

    System.out.println("Teller:" + " " + name + " " + "This transaction will process:"     + " " + dateProcessed);
}


public void acctStuff()
{
    if(acct instenceof checkingAccount)
     { //do checking stuff}
    else { //do savings stuff}
}
```

let me know if I missed something or if something doesnt make sense